# Is Postgres Ignoring the "trust" in pg_hba.conf File?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following lines in my `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32         trust
host    all         all         ::1/128              trust
host    all         all         localhost            trust
```

and I've restarted Postgres.  When I connect at the command line everything works as expected:

```
$ psql -U me -W
Password for user me: # I can type any password and it will work
psql (9.5.7)
Type "help" for help.

me=#
```

However, when I connect through a software library (the Node library `pg`, through the library `knex`) I get an error:

```
password authentication failed for user "me"
```

I'm not specifically looking for a fix,  I'm just trying to understand how this is even possible.  If I just told Postgres to trust anyone, how can I still be getting errors about authentication failing?  Was there something wrong with my `pg_hba.conf` entries, or does Postgres just choose to ignore them under certain circumstances, or ....

**EDIT**

In case it helps the database connection URL my program is using to connect is:`postgres://localhost:5432/mydb`.

Comment: Can you take a look at the log? (It might contain a hint about which IP the library is actually using; which *may* not be what you expect)

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing being logged except that error message and a useless stack trace.  If I understand you correctly though, my library might be connecting some way *other* than `127.0.0.1/32` or `::1/128` or `localhost`, which would then cause it not to hit my rules, and thus explain why they aren't working ... is that right?  If so, is there any way to define a wildcard entry in `pg_hba.conf` that will match any IP? I tried using `samenet` but it didn't help.

Comment: You can use `all`... and try. If you can connect, then use `SELECT inet_client_addr()`. You may try also adding some `local` entries, in case `pg` uses a local unix socket.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately `all` didn't help.  I logged my connection URL, and it was `postgres://localhost:5432/mydatabase`, so I tried adding `host all all localhost:5432 trust` ... but that didn't help.  So I'm pretty sure I'm coming in over localhost, but for whatever reason my "trust localhost" line doesn't seem to get used (and adding the port doesn't help).

Comment: About `psql -U me -W` If you don't specifying the host address (`-h` option) - `psql` (and any other clients I suppose) uses `local` connection type. So, first of all, try to connect to DB using `psql -U me -h localhost`.

Comment: Or try to use `postgres:///mydb` URL

Comment: That was very interesting! `postgres:///mydb` didn't do anything, but when I did `psql -U me -h localhost` I was prompted for my password ... and it actually cared what password I entered (despite my `localhost trust` rule in `pg_hba.conf`)!  So it's clear that both `psql` and my code ignore the `pg_hba.conf` rule, when I use `localhost` at least ... now if I could only figure out why/how to fix it.

Comment: Woot, I finally got my code working with a connection URL of `postgres://me:mypassword@localhost:5432/mydatabase`.  That solves the problem that started all this, but I'd still really like to understand why the `pg_hba.conf` rules only seemed to get used some of the time (eg. not when I did `psql -U me -h localhost`).  If anyone can explain that (ideally in the form of an answer that I can accept and give you points for) that would be awesome.

Comment: Did you restart PostgreSQL after changing `pg_hba.conf`?

Comment: Yes (or at least I did at >90% of the time; it's possible I forgot to restart once or twice, but I definitely did several times after adding the `localhost` rule).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you did `psql -U me -h localhost`, psql failed to connect because it doesn't know what database to connect to.

Solution is `psql -U me -h localhost -d database_name`

Hope this helps.